calc-expand function return nil in script mode
I would like to write a function that evaluates a polynomial (given by the list of its coefficients) for a given value of the variable.
When the variable is in literal form, I would like the result to be given in expanded standard form.
The problem is that the calc-expand function returns nil.
(defun horner(p x_0) 
 "Évalue le polynôme P pour la valeur X_0 en
  utilisant le schéma de Horner.  P est donné par la liste de ses
  coefficients par ordre de puissances décroissantes"
 


   (interactive)
   (seq-reduce
    (lambda(x y)(format "%s*(%s)+%s" x_0 x y))
    p 0))    

=> horner

(calc-eval(horner '(4 3 2 1) 'x)) => "x*(x*(4 x + 3) + 2) + 1"

(calc-expand(calc-eval(horner '(4 3 2 1) 'x)))

=> nil

% Je voudrais obtenir 4*x^3+3*x^2+2*x+1

From the usual Calc interface, the expand (a x) command returns exactly what I want to get.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

@NickD. The problem only occurs when the calc-expand command is sent from elisp code. I wanted to emphasize this point.

I understand but that's not the meaning of the elisp tag. AFAICT, there is no tag that will capture your meaning, so unless you introduce a new one and document it, it's better to leave it out. In any case, people who might be willing to take a look will do so on the basis of the calc tag mainly, so I don't think a new tag is needed.

Try this:
(calc-eval (format "expand(%s)" (horner '(4 3 2 1) 'x)))

What you give to calc-eval is a string and it returns a string. It is the simplest way to use calc from your program - see Calling Calc from Your Lisp Programs in the Calc manual.
If you want to use lower-level functions (like calc-expand), you'll first need to understand the difference between calc-foo and calcFunc-foo (e.g. calc-expand and calcFunc-expand): the first uses the stack, the second is used by the first to do calculations. All of that is described in the manual: see Programming Calc with Lisp.
